# Accessing an object with dot notation using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use React-DnD and I have this code:

```
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "./Constants";

type DraggableGameAnswerProps = {
    type: string
}

function DraggableGameAnswer(props: DraggableGameAnswerProps)
{
    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.{props.type},
        collect: (monitor) => ({
          isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
        })
      }))
}

export default DraggableGameAnswer;
```

but the line

```
type: ItemTypes.{props.type}
```

doesn't work.

Constants.tsx

```
export const ItemTypes = {
    raspuns1: 'raspuns1',
    raspuns2: 'raspuns2',
    raspuns3: 'raspuns3',
    raspuns4: 'raspuns4'
}
```

In the parent component, I want to decide which of those 4 options I want to pass onto the children,
and then send through the props raspuns1/raspuns2/raspuns3/raspuns4.

In the above code you can see my approach - I also tried with bracket notation, but it hasn't worked either.

Is it possible to access the data in the object ItemTypes this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I geuss you look for: `ItemTypes[prop.type]`

Comment: I guess you meant "props.type". If so, now I get Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ raspuns1: string; raspuns2: string; raspuns3: string; raspuns4: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ raspuns1: string; raspuns2: string; raspuns3: string; raspuns4: string; }'.

Comment: Yes true because it cannot index it. So the entire line would be:

`type: (ItemType as Record<string, any>)[props.type],`. Or update the type of your ItemTypes as follows:

`export const ItemTypes: Record<string, any> = {
    raspuns1: 'raspuns1',
    raspuns2: 'raspuns2',
    raspuns3: 'raspuns3',
    raspuns4: 'raspuns4'
}`

Comment: Shouldn't someting like export const ItemTypes: {[key: string]: string]} = { ... } work too? I get "; expected" for my approach

Comment: Does it already work? It should be the same indeed.

Comment: Your way works, my way doesn't. I get an error "; expected"

Comment: If it works, could you mark the answer as answered.